# Ros on Window tutorial?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, windows10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have just installed ROS on Windows and wish to know if there are any tutorials that can get me started.
Currently the tutorials are for linux. Kindly do a tutorial on creating ROS enviroment, ROS package and ROS nodes/topics on a window server.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353805/ros-on-window-tutorial??/) by [loguna](https://answers.ros.org/users/39943/loguna/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2020-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://ms-iot.github.io/ROSOnWindows/GettingStarted/Setup.html

---

Originally posted by [loguna](https://answers.ros.org/users/39943/loguna/) with karma: 98 on 2021-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0